# Why can I see the status of subscribers reflected in ExactTarget, but the changes are not reflected in the API results without significant delays?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk

I am in the process of integrating ExactTarget for a project, and in my testing I have seen long delays in what the API (FuelSDK-C#) returns. For instance, I will set a list with a test user, and see the email open and click through almost immediately in ExactTarget, but then when I request an update through the API to my plugin, there is often a 5+ minute delay in getting the changes to come through.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to plan for status changes to take longer.  Status changes are cascaded to multiple places -- more than click and open activities.

There's the overall status, (hidden) business unit status, unsub events, status change tracking extract source, etc.